# Getting last two digits of Sequence Date in R

Tags: r, substring, numeric, substr

I have sequence date:

```
names<-format(seq.Date(as.Date("2012-11-01"),as.Date("2012-12-01"),
                by = 'months'),format = "%Y%m")
```

How can I get the last two digit, like the result for last two digits of names[1] is  11?

Comment: You said you have a sequence of dates, just format to `%m` instead of `%Y%m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `stringr` package you can just put

`stringr::str_sub(string = names, start = -2, end = -1)`

Comment: The result is a string type. So make sure to transform it to integer when you want to perform any calculations with the result.

Answer (score 0):

There can be tenths of ways. The simpliest I could invent was to find the remainder of intiger division:

```
as.integer(names)  %% 100
```

that returns:

```
[1] 11 12
```

Technically these are integers. If you stricktly require characters apply `as.character()` to the result to cast the type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `substr()`:

```
names = substr(names, nchar(names)-1, nchar(names))
```

The result is:

```
[1] "11" "12"
```

Or as integer:

```
names = as.integer(substr(names, nchar(names)-1, nchar(names))
```

Result:

```
[1] 11 12
```